# How to make Intel Parallel in Visual Studio run .f77, .f95, etc.?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, intel-parallel-studio

It seems that after installing Intel Parallel XE 2020 on Visual Studio 2019, I cannot run some extensions of Fortran such as .f77 and f95. It runs .f90 for example, but how can I fix it to run every extension?

Comment: If you have a programming tool question, by all means ask it. But most of what you have posted is just a rant and editorializing and doesn't belong here.

Comment: No I didn't. I was simply advising to just focus on asking a good question and leaving the angst out of it. It doesn't help anyone to include it. Thank you for listening to that advice.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32074545/makefile-for-fortran-files-with-f03-extention-not-working and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269076/correct-suffix-for-fortran-2003-source-file-intel-fortran-compiler  I added Visual Studio to the title so that it is not a simple duplicate but do not be surprised if the members of the community decide it is a duplicate.

Comment: @VladimirF So it means Intel Parallel can work just as fine, somewhere other than Visual Studio?

Comment: @Wolfgang No, it just means that your question is how to set it up specifically in Visual Studio. The links I gave you above show how to do it on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is in `Tools/Options` and then `Intel Compilers` and `IFORT/General` under **Sources**.

Add the `.f77` and `.f95` extensions to the appropriate file format.

[image: scr]

Comment: It still does not recognize the .f95 files.
_The thread 0x9e0 has exited with code 0 (0x0)._
_The program '[3880] Console1.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)._

Comment: @Wolfgang That is a completely different problem. Start a new question and include your code and enable all debugging checks (`-g -check` on the commmand line, some option in VS). See [mcve]. Try also renaming your file to the usual .f90.